# Count occurrences in a table then use for finding average

Tags: mysql, sql

table 1

```
categoryid   categoryname   categorydescription
1               a             zzzzzzz
2               b              yyyyyy
3               c               uuuuu
```

table 2

```
carid caryear carmodel carprice catid(foreign key to category id )
1        xxxx    aaaa    xxxx    1
2       xxxx     bbbb    xxxx    3
3       xxxx     cccc    xxxx    4
3       xxxx     dddd    xxxx    3
4       xxxxx    eeee    xxxx    1
```

results

```
categoryname                               averageprice                         total cars
a               sum price of same category car / no of same category cars           1
b               sum price of same category car / no of same category cars           2
c               sum price of same category car / no of same category cars           2
```

Comment: 1 a zzzzzzz 2 b yyyyyy 3 c uuuuu??????????????

Comment: There's an aggregate called AVG() for average and another called COUNT (and another called SUM if you really want to DIY).

Comment: You have a referential integrity problem with your data; there's no category ID of 4 shown in that table.

Answer (score 2):

You can write:

```
 SELECT category.categoryname,
        AVG(car.carprice) AS "averageprice",
        COUNT(car.carid) AS "total cars"
   FROM category
   LEFT
  OUTER
   JOIN car
     ON car.catid = category.categoryid
  GROUP
     BY category.categoryname
;
```

Notes:

- You didn't mention the names of your tables, so I had to guess.
- This will include categories that don't have any cars. If you'd only like to include categories that have at least one car, drop the `LEFT OUTER` part.

Comment: Doesn't this need a `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: @BobDuell: Whoops, yes. I've fixed the answer now. Thank you!